# jQuery Toggle Breaks Propagation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, toggle, responsive-design, breakpoints

Does jQuery Toggle break propagation?

My problem being is that I am building a Responsive Menu, and when I resize the browser to a width of the only breakpoint I have. jQuery's Toggle function breaks my propagation.

Here's the example: http://www.stlredtails.com/construction

If you resize your browser to less than or equal to 1024px, click on the Navigation button at the top, and try to click on the Contact link, once the menu is displayed. It doesn't propagate, and then if you resize the browser above 1024px... The Contact link does propagate. I do not recall having this problem with the Slide toggling.

Also if you resize the browser to or below 1024px. You have to refresh the page for the event to even fire once you click on the navigation button? Does jQuery's Toggle break this as well?

jQuery below:

```
    if((window.outerWidth && window.outerWidth > 1024) || (document.body.clientWidth && document.body.clientWidth > 1024)){
        jQuery(".navigation > ul > li").hoverIntent(
            function() {
               jQuery(this).children('ul').slideDown();
            },
            function(){
               jQuery(this).children('ul').slideUp();
            }
        );
        jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > ul").hover(
            function() {
               jQuery(this).children('ul').show();
            },
            function() {
               jQuery(this).children('ul').hide();
            }
        );
    }
    if((window.outerWidth && window.outerWidth <= 1024) || (document.body.clientWidth && document.body.clientWidth <= 1024)){
        jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > a").each( function() {
            if(jQuery(this).siblings("ul").length) {
                jQuery(this).removeAttr("href");
            }
        });
        jQuery(".navigation > span > a#navigation").toggle(
            function() {
               jQuery(this).parent().siblings("ul").css("display", "block");
            },
            function() {
               jQuery(this).parent().siblings("ul").css("display", "none");
            }
        );
        jQuery(".navigation > ul > li > a").toggle(
            function() {
               jQuery(this).siblings("ul").css("display", "block");
            },
            function() {
               jQuery(this).siblings("ul").css("display", "none");
            }
        );
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Thank you!

Comment: show your click handler code. Also why `removeAttr('href')` ?

Comment: The Toggle is the replacement of the click handler.

Comment: `toggle()` as click handler  is deprecated. Why is the click handling being managed within the resize? You will compound handlers if you never unbind them. If element is hidden , won't be able to clcik it. seems to me all your resize should do is change display

Comment: Because I am trying to use hoverIntent() for viewports greater than 1024px and toggle() for viewports less than or equal to 1024px in width.

Comment: but you aren't considering what happens when user changes window size and reverts back

Comment: How would I even address that? I've tried using the resize function?

Comment: can apply hoverintent and click handlers to class of elements > 1024, and different handlers for class (or ID) of mini nav and shouldn't need to modify after page load. Resize would only change display

Comment: I appreciate all your help @charlietfl, but how would I rewrite that? I am far from a JavaScript/jQuery master.

Comment: Start by unwrapping all the code shown from width conditions.

Comment: But if I unwrap them... Then everything is completely broken.

Comment: define 'borken`...errors thrown in console? visual or??

Comment: whatever is broken in console would cause visual. Errors will block script running. Focus on what is in console